# An AJAX HTTP error occurred.HTTP Result Code: 200Debugging information follows

Tags: php, drupal-7

After update the drupal version from 7.36 to 7.43.

I am not able access any of the views. It is popup the ajax error message with HTTP Result Code: 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Go to the following folder,

Root path of the drupal installation and find the folder **misc/ajax.js** (**drupal 7.43**)

Replace the **ajax.js** file from the **drupal version 7.36**

Then flush the drupal cache

Now check the view.

That's it

Answer (score 0):

**Solution2:**

Go to **admin/structure/view**,

Click the **settings** tab in that click the **advanced** tab,

So here under the **DEBUGGING** section select the **“Disable JavaScript with Views”** checkbox and click the save configuration button to save the settings.

Now go to view and check it out.